# Proving that $2^n$ is greater than a binomial expression

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, limits

This is from a friend's textbook. There is a really obvious counting argument, but it is a calculus, not a combinatorics, textbook, and the answer probably involves messing up with algebraic equations.

> By considering $(1+x)^n$ for suitable $x$, show $$2^n > \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}$$

The counting argument is that the LHS is the total number of ways to choose any set of items out of $n$ items, while the RHS is the number of ways to choose *three* items, which is clearly much less.

However, I can't seem to think of an algebraic method of doing this. The hint seems to be related to the binomial theorem, but how does that involve $2^n$?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573350/trying-to-show-that-n-choose-k-less-than-2n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^n=(1+1)^n=\binom n 0+\binom n 1+\binom n 2+\binom n 3+\ldots+\binom n n$